# file_get_contents() with POST method shows as GET?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Using Google App Engine, when calling my API using POST method, it shows as GET - why?

This is my code:

```
function call_api($client_id, $client_secret, $data) {
    $api_url = 'http://myapp.com/api.php';

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . Base64_encode("$client_id:$client_secret") . "\r\nContent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context);
    return $result;
}
```

The first line of api.php is:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SERVER); echo "</pre>";
```

And within that output, I see:

```
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
```

How/why could this be happening?

It's also worth mentioning that the method shows as POST when testing this code on GAE's SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out and I need to answer my own question because it's a doozy!!

Whilst the url is http `$api_url = 'http://myapp.com/api.php';`, as per everything else, the GAE app.yaml file serves all scripts as https as per:

```
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
  secure: always
```

This means that the page that calls my function above is http**s** so the api call doesn't like the request because of [Cross-orgin source sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

The solution was to simply change the `$api_url` to be http**s**.